# Harvesting pixels using GRASS GIS

Tags: raster, grass-gis, network

having a binary raster map of pixels of interest,
a road network,
and a target point,
my goal is to get a raster map with network pixels having as value the number of pixels of interest they allow to reach.

Would you know how i could use GRASS GIS tools to perform this?

The steps i foresee are:

- rasterize the network using `v.to.rast`
- compute pixels of interest distance to the network using `r.grow.distance`,
- compute a direction map with `r.cost`,
- add the target point to the network with `v.net operation=connect`,
- alter network lines directions toward the target,
- rasterize the network again using `v.to.rast use=dir`,
- overwrite the direction map with network direction pixels with `r.mapcalc`,
- build a directed graph from direction map,
- set a value of 1 to nodes that are on pixels of interest,
- perform a graph traversal toward the target, cumulating nodes values.

By now, i still don't know how to revert lines directions or build the graph.

Answer (score 1):

To revert line direction you can go with [v.edit](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.edit.html) and the **flip** option.

Answer (score 1):

Using `r.watershed -s` with *cells of interest* provided as `flow` on a *distance to network* raster map (from `r.grow.distance`), i obtained the accumulation map answering our issues.